# Can Bogo Sort Outperform Bubble Sort in Certain Scenarios?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

In my recent comparison of the Bubble Sort and Bogo Sort algorithms, specifically analyzing their performance in sorting an array of length 9, Bubble Sort consistently exhibited faster sorting times (no surprises there!). However, I'm curious if there are any conceivable scenarios where Bogo Sort might unexpectedly outperform Bubble Sort in terms of sorting speed.

Comment: If you refer to the *random* shuffling algorithm, of course, you could get lucky some day. If you refer to the deterministic version of Bogo Sort, then of course, you can make sure your input array gets sorted by the first permutation that Bogo Sort will apply.

Comment: @trincot yes the random shuffling. thanks for your answer. So it is possible to outperform other algorithms.

Comment: "It's possible for Bogosort to outperform actual proper sorting algorithms" is about as insightful a sentence as "It's possible to get hit by lightning while winning the lottery on February 29th"

Comment: @Stef: For a 9-element array, there is a 1-in-362880 chance that the correct order is generated on the first try. Where I live, both getting hit by lightning and winning the lottery are far less likely, even independently, let alone combined.

Comment: @JörgWMittag My school's annual lottery only has a thousand tickets, and the prize-giving ceremony takes place on top of a hill just below a tall pine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is.

For Bogo Sort of a 9-element array, there is a 1-in-362880 chance that the correct ordering is generated on the first try.

The worst case for Bubble Sort is when the original array is reverse-sorted. In that case, Bubble Sort of a 9-element array requires 36 swaps and at least 36 comparisons.

The same array in Bogo Sort, if you are *extremely* lucky, requires only 1 comparison to realize it is not already sorted, at most 9 swaps to generate the random shuffling, and another 8 comparisons to verify that it is correctly sorted.

So, Bubble Sort of a reverse-sorted 9-element array always requires 36 swaps and at least 36 comparisons, whereas there is a 0.0002755731922% chance that Bogo Sort can do it in 9 comparisons and at most 9 swaps.

On the other hand, there is of course also an infinitesimally small chance that Bogo Sort will fail generate the correct sorting within a bounded amount of tries and thus run for an unbounded amount of time.

Comment: Pedantic nitpick here. While there is a very small chance that Bogo Sort will not yield a sorted outcome within any particular ***finite*** number of attempts, infinity is not a number and Bogo Sort will not run infinitely. The logic is the same as the various proofs that [0.999... == 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...).

Comment: Thanks. "Unbounded" captures it better, I think, without going into the fine details of what "almost always" means in probability theory.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. your comments and answers were really informative.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think this hits more on the concept of something happening "with probability 1" rather than "almost surely".

Comment: @pjs: Probably. (Pun intended.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag I agree with the “unbounded” edit, but think retaining “never” is a misstatement.

Comment: @pjs: Since we're being pedantic: mathematically you can't say that Bogosort won't run indefinitely. The correct way to describe the algorithm is to say that it has an expected runtime of O(n!) and it *almost surely* terminates, but it is not *certain* that it terminates. Look up the term “almost surely” on Wikipedia if you're not familiar.